# How to set Textbox to wait for input mode in tkinter.ttk.Entry

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using `ttk.Entry` as my input. I want to ask if there is a way to be in the input mode without a mouse click. By the way, the result I want is not to use `Entry.insert` to give the value.

It is like this:

Cannot Input
[image]

To be:

Can Input
[image]

Comment: `Entry.focus()` ?

Comment: It is `focus_set()`. Look at my answer

Comment: There is another related method called `focus_get()` which gives you info about the widget which is in focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use focus_set() -

```
E1 = Entry(...)
E1.pack()

E1.focus_set()
```

Comment: Check python [**documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3/) for more info